# О грамматическом роде синонимов

Tags: синонимы

Пара луна - месяц, если не ошибаюсь, уникальна для русского языка.
Слова достаточно древние, синонимичны в основном значении, от разных корней образованы и имеют разный грамматический род.

*Когда-то синонимичными считались ещё пары собака-пёс и лошадь-конь, но те времена давно ушли. При этом, кстати, лошадь изначально было словом мужского рода, а конь испытывал сильные колебания.*

Больше я таких пар не знаю. Кто-нибудь вспомнит ещё? Современные заимствования не предлагать, они не интересны по самой сути вопроса.

Чтобы занятие не казалось бессмыленной игрой, напомню, что для предков грамматически род слова определялся совсем не бросанием монетки, как это может показаться сейчас. За ним стояла целая система принципов одушевления того или иного предмета. Так что разный грамматический род у одного и того же объекта дейтвительно любопытен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может быть, Вы имели в виду не синонимы, а морфологические варианты одной эпохи образования? Сейчас таких пар множество, причины разные(изменение и устаревание значения, исчезновение параллельных форм рода,переход в диалекты ):гребень – гребёнка, закута - закут, вольера - вольер,скирда-скирд, ставень -ставня.проток -- протока,жар-жара, гроздь - грозд (устаревшее, осталась разница во мн. ч.: гроздья(ж.р., грозди - муж.))тень-тенёк.

Интересно сравнить ребёнок и дитя. Когда-то ребёнок тоже было среднего рода:робя(с юсом малым), как и дитя -с ятем и юсом малым.
Чадо-когда-то имело параллельные формы-чад –сын, чада-дочь, чадо –дитя., чадь-дети.

Comment: >Вы имели в виду не синонимы, а морфологические варианты одной эпохи образования? 

Нет. Вопрос получился экспромтом, я сам тольком не могу сформулировать, что хотел сказать, но точно не это... Хотя сама такая мысль насчет одной эпохи мне нравится. Спасибо.  

Хорошо бы еще снять терминологическую двусмысленность "морфологические варианты"...

Comment: Разумеется,пара луна-месяц к ним не относится.Это синонимы - родовая пара по соотнесённости с биологическим полом.(Ф.Буслаев писал о перенесении половых отличий на предметы неодушевленные,у него посмотрите) Путь-дорога, гребень-гребёнка, тень-тенёк - то же самое.Кстати, лошадь-конь и сейчас синонимичны, но не пара, пара конь-кобыла.Морфологич.вариант - полное тождество слова, совпадение семантики и морфем, кроме категории рода(скирда-скирд, закута-закут.)http://rudocs.exdat.com/docs/index-378772.html?page=12

Comment: Людмила, я для начала хотел только узнать, что вы прнимаете под упортребленным вами тенрмином "морфологические варианты". Без этого понимание вашего текста невозможно. Особенно то, что "разумется".

Если вы этим секретом подеоитесь, я как-нибудь и дальнейшее оценю.

Answer (score 3):

туча-облако?
путь - дорога?))

Comment: Туча и облако - синонимы только у гидромета. В быту это разные вещи.
Вот "путь и дорога" - надо подумать. Тоже ведь не полные синонимы.
Но в любом случае - спасибо.

Comment: Око- глаз?

Comment: Да, но опять-таки "глаз" в этом значении - очень позднее явление, XVII век, кажется.

Answer (score 1):

Огонь-пламя, рай-Небо, ад-пекло, азбука-букварь, мрак-темень (темнота), ребенок-дитя. Правда, трудно сказать, когда возникло каждое из этих слов.

Comment: Да, спасибо, хотя не все из этих пар "подходят" по признаку полной синонимичности в основном занчении, но это уже не столь важно.  

Я уже понял, что слегка погорячился с формулировкой об "уникальности". Я постараюсь попозже сформулировать, что я имел в виду.